# Is it possible to call an already existing JavaScript outside of PageLoad()?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

So due to particular circumstances on the legacy application that I am assigned to work on, I need to write code to call JavaScript on a button click. The JS function I wish to call already exists on a page, but it takes a parameter than can only be populated AFTER a button click (horrible design, but I don't have a say in rewriting too much functionality, as it is only a legacy application).

How can I do this?

I have tried code like this

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType, "Key", "preExistingFunction('SomeParameter');", True)
```

Comment: The code above does not work, unfortunately.

Comment: Any errors in the javascript console of your browser, after that button click? Please elaborate on "does not work".

Comment: Sorry should have clarified. No, there are no errors in the console. I set a breakpoint in the dev tools as well, and it does not even hit the function.

Comment: You need to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which will help you narrow down the issue and lead to an answerable question without constantly having to ask for more detail.